# Reading two Complete different dataframes from a single csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Essentially having trouble reading all of the contents of a single csv file. 
The first few lines of the csv file, contains 7 columns.The rest of the file contains 13 columns. I can read them fine, separately at different times, but i want to know if there is a way i could read them at once. Some photos of the csv file; (**NOTE**: You can ignore the nans created for the 1st dataframe, they wont be needed (only the first row will be use), i just showed them here for a full overview)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I have tried using pandas `read_csv` twice but will either give an error, or the file wasnt read properly. ie. if i read the first dataframe first using pandas, the second time i read the 2nd dataframe, it would have skipped the first few rows. ie. the dataframe would have a "Date(NZST)" staring at around 1940 instead of 1910 as is shown on the image.
eg.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 2, nrows = 1, delimiter = '\t',header = None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 8,delimiter = '\t')
```

If i do it the other way around, eg. `df2` is first read before `df1`, it will give an `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` when i read `df1`

- Im thingking from the error given it suggests that this can be fixed (maybe), if i somehow reset the reader, but i have been searching endlessly, but cant seem to find a way.
- I was also thingking of reading only 7 columns  as the rest of the columns wont be needed anyway ie;
  neither cols below works

```
cols = list(range(0,7))
cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
df1 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 2,delimiter = '\t',usecols=cols)
```

Some samples of my Data;
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15PwpWIh13tyOyzFUTiE9LgrxUMm-9gh6?usp=sharing

Comment: your file is not correctly formated `csv` so you can't read it with one `read_csv`. Correct csv has only rows with data and every row has the same number of colums (cells). First part doesn't even look like csv. If you use opened `file` instead of filename then you can't read previous data - because this is how files works. `file` has "pointer" which remebers where you stoped reading and at next reading it starts at this place/pointer. You would have to use `seek()` to move pointer back - but you can do the same by reopening file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but still better/simplier is read file twice in pandas if want correct set `types` of columns by default - not all columns to strings:

```
r = [0,1,3,4,5,6,7]
df2 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = r,  delimiter = '\t',header = None, names=range(13))
print (df2.head())
                   0           1           2        3            4        5   \
0     Woodhill Forest        1402      A64741  -36.749      174.431       30   
1             Station  Date(NZST)  Time(NZST)  Tmax(C)  Period(Hrs)  Tmin(C)   
2  -36.7490, 174.4310  1951 01 01       09:00        -            -     17.8   
3  -36.7490, 174.4310  1951 01 02       09:00     24.9           24     15.6   
4  -36.7490, 174.4310  1951 01 03       09:00     17.2           24     12.7   

            6         7            8         9          10           11    12  
0            G       NaN          NaN       NaN        NaN          NaN   NaN  
1  Period(Hrs)  Tgmin(C)  Period(Hrs)  Tmean(C)  RHmean(%)  Period(Hrs)  Freq  
2           24         -            -         -          -            -     D  
3           24         -            -         -          -            -     D  
4           24         -            -         -          -            -     D
```

Another solution should be read file by lines and create 2 lists for 2 DataFrames, but again get all strings - need convert each column to integer or float or if necessary to datetimes.

---

```
file = 'wgenf - 2019-04-20T204905.009.genform1_proc'
df1 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 2, nrows = 1, delimiter = '\t',header = None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 8,delimiter = '\t', na_values=['-'])
print (df1.dtypes)
0     object
1      int64
2     object
3    float64
4    float64
5      int64
6     object
7    float64
dtype: object

print (df2.dtypes)
Station           object
Date(NZST)        object
Time(NZST)        object
Tmax(C)          float64
Period(Hrs)      float64
Tmin(C)          float64
Period(Hrs).1    float64
Tgmin(C)         float64
Period(Hrs).2    float64
Tmean(C)         float64
RHmean(%)        float64
Period(Hrs).3    float64
Freq              object
dtype: object
```

Comment: I didnt know you can specify, row numbers to be skipped, thank you for your input. I think your first solution is better and faster i think, its just a matter of converting to what types they are.  Your second solution of reading the two dataframes would flag some lost data, as i have mentioned in my original post. around 10,000 rows would be lost to be specific. I also found a solution, by capturing the error, using try, pass and except, do you think using them is bad practice? Lastly thank you again!!!

Comment: @WDS - I think there is no problem use `try-except` statement here, especially if not clean data - I think clean data like first row header and another values data.